# Mailgun - text/html attachment has broken text encoding when downloaded from store

Tags: html, encoding, character-encoding, mailgun

I've run into an issue with while using Mailgun routes. When using the store & notify route on an e-mail that has text/html attachment with special chars and I download it using the URL received in the POST data, the characters are broken. Is this a mailgun issue or am I doing something wrong? I believe I should get the exact same data using the storage as it was in the original e-mail without fiddling with stuff.

Answer (score 0):

I solved this by properly decoding the data in my server after receiving it, but I think there was still a problem with how mailgun stores the attachments, as the files they store looked broken in the same way as for me when I didn't properly decode the chunks I recieved.